# AndEngine Box2D - Rectangular Body transform to a line?

Tags: box2d, andengine, physics, platform

I want to make a doodle jump like, I create two body one for the player and one for the platform, but instead of bouncing on the Platform Body, the player can jump on all the line at the Y coords of the body. Don't know why.

```
    private void creerPlateformes(int n)
{
    int pX[] = new int[n];
    int pY[] = new int[n];
    pX[0] = CAMERA_WIDTH/ 2-60;
    pY[0] = 780;    
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        if (i!=0)
        {
            final Random r = new Random();          
            pX[i] = r.nextInt(464-16)+16;
            pY[i] = pY[i-1]-r.nextInt(200-100)+100;
        }

    plateforme[i] = new Sprite(pX[i], pY[i], mPlateformeTextureRegion, getVertexBufferObjectManager());
    plateforme[i].setScale(1);
    plateforme[i].setUserData("plateforme");
    final FixtureDef PLATEFORME_FIX = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    plateformeBody[i] = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(physicsWorld, plateforme[i], BodyType.StaticBody, PLATEFORME_FIX);
    plateformeBody[i].setUserData("plateforme");
    scene.attachChild(plateforme[i]);
    }

}
```

Tell me if you need more code, but I think the problem may be there.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding what happens. Is it this: the player bounces on areas that do not have a platform? The Y position seems correct, but the X position is not. Is that the problem?

Comment: Yes, exactly, I really don't know why..

Comment: This is only a guess, but does the Sprite "plateforme[i]" contain transparent pixels? The bounding box of the shape used by box 2D will be the same as the sprite bounding box.

Comment: Yes this sprite contain transparent pixels, i try with a sprite without transparent pixels, but don't seems to work.. My player still bounce on all the X axis at the right Y position

Comment: @SebastienServouze do yo have borders on the left/right side of the screen (that prevent the player from running endless to the left/right? i must admit, that i  never played doodle jump, just got bored 1k times by the tv ad.
to clearify my question: in x-direction, you have a space of 16px from the border of the scene, is your player even small enough to fall through these holes?

Comment: nevermind :-/ i can't see anything wrong from the code (except instantiating your random, your initalization of x[0]/y[0] and the PlateFormeFix inside the for loop, but that's not the matter imho)...out of curiosity, would you tell us the width of your camera and your sprite?

Comment: Thank you for your interest :). Camera is 480x800 (Width x Height) and sprite is 63x63. If the sprite X goes to 0 or less, sprite X = 480, so if it goes by the right, the sprite respawn at the left, like doodle jump

Comment: that was unclear, meant the sprite of the block? or is that 63x63? and by saying "if the sprite goes to 0 or less" you mean the player imho - did you probably forget to move the players body and only moved the sprite? then it wouldn't make me wonder, that he doesn't fall down :-O just another blind guess ;-)

Comment: You put me on something, my sprite moves are done by a function moving the player coords with sensor event, maybe i'm not using a move method which can be used with the Box2d physics ?

Comment: Ok, so you were right, i check it and my body X coord doesn't move. So, how can i make it follow my sprite ? Use body.setTransform ?

Comment: see my answer (following now ;-) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you told in the comments, it's not, that the players body was moved, instead you moved the sprite alone  ;-)

moving the player by the sensor event, you could use something like

```
playerBody.setLinearVelocity (float vX, float vY)
```

with the x value depending on your sensor, the y value should be something like your jump-speed imho

then you don't need to move the sprite anymore, since it will be moved with the bodies moving

Comment: Thanks, you solve my problem. That was that ! I don't want to be boring, but, i got another little problem, my Accelerometer seems to be long to react.. Or a kind of long reaction time you see ? I use LinearDumping but it's not really like i want..

Comment: hmm. i would ask you to put this in another question, since it would be way out of the scope of this question. add some code and me or some users will try to help ;-)